# What's the advantage of returning exceptions over using try catch blocks in async callback chain?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, twisted, deferred

After looking at [Twisted's `Deferred` class](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html) and [HeavyLifters Deferred Library](https://github.com/heavylifters/deferred-js) I noticed that errbacks are fired if the previous resultant value was an instance of the `Failure` class. This got me thinking: is there any particular reason for returning a special object to denote an error instead of just throwing an error.

From what I deduced I feel it's better to throw errors because:

1. Any value can be thrown.
2. If the value thrown is not caught, it propagates up the call stack.
3. There's no need for a special `Failure` or `Error` class.
4. It makes the callbacks look more like synchronous code.
5. The exception may be handled at any level of the call stack.

Some of the disadvantages I noticed were:

1. Trying blocks of code and catching error may cause a performance hit to the code.
2. If an exception is not caught then it stops the execution of the rest of the callback chain.
3. Asynchronous programming is essential the polar opposite of using try catch blocks.

I'm trying to weigh the odds and figure out which method of reporting errors is more suitable in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Failure` class in Twisted has a number of handy methods that make it useful, independent of the features in `Deferred` for running error handling callbacks.  Browse the API documentation and you'll find useful methods, for example for formatting tracebacks and checking exception types.  `Failure` is also a handy place to put some really gross hacks for getting nice integration with generators for `twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks` and for special support code for Cython which generates subtly different exceptions.

`Failure` is also a good place to keep the traceback state together with the exception.  Python exceptions normally don't carry stack information, so if you only have an exception, you can't find out where it was raised.  That can be a major drawback any time you want to handle an exception outside of the `except` block that caught it.

Finally, being able to return a `Failure` enables this simple, commonly useful pattern:

```
def handleOneErrorCase(reason):
    if not thisCaseApplies(reason):
        return reason

    handleThisCase(reason)

someDeferred.addErrback(handleOneErrorCase)
```

This frequently shows up in `Deferred`-using code.  It's convenient, happens to be a bit more performant on CPython, and also has the advantage that the original stack information in `reason` is preserved (if the exception were re-raised by the error handler, the stack at *that* point would replace the original stack, obscuring the original cause of the exception).

Answer (score 0):

Errors are usually returned with callback in an async environment as errors cannot be caught outside the async function. For example in javascript if you try:

```
try {
    setTimeout(function() { throw new Error(); }, 0);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught it.');
}
```

Then the exception will go uncaught. This has to do with the fact that async functions are reregistered and then later called by the event loop in a different stack and as such the exception won't bubble up the original stack.

Comment: That's pretty obvious. It's because the function is being called within the `setTimeout` function which catches all errors itself. The simple workaround is to create a closure which catches all the errors and fires the callback. So instead of passing the function to `setTimeout` you pass the closure wrapping the function instead. What I really want to know is if it's better to use try catch blocks within the closure or check the return value of the wrapped function.